# How to get Latitude and Longitude in react native?

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I need to know how to get latitude and longitude in react native for a http.
example:

> http://example.com/TEST/app.do?do=savestatus&u=user&lat=latitude&lng=longitude...

thanks for the HELP!!!.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RN's navigator API if what you're looking for is a simple way to get your long and lat:

```
const options = { enableHighAccuracy: true };
const self = this;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
function success(pos) {
    const { latitude, longitude } = pos.coords;
    self.setState({ location: `${latitude},${longitude}`});
}
```

[source](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation#getcurrentposition)